# Dash not working on Focal Fossa

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, unity-dash

I installed Ubuntu Focal Fossa in a dualboot situation. Windows is working just fine, grub 2 also working.
Every time i boot in Ubuntu, i takes a while for the "Show app" option to start working, is that normal?
Also, my dash never shows me the open applications, it stays blank.

If anyone could help, i would really appreciate it

Comment: if you installed on a laptop, then check on login screen which session it is.. if it's wayland change it to x11 and in gnome-tweaks disable the animations that could also help...

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you guide me through the wayland to x11 change?

Comment: found out that i'm using x11